# How are Razor Page View Component paths searched? I fail to get them working, .NET Core tries to include irrelevant model

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I cannot get ViewComponent to be included in a page.

I have a folder structure:

`- Pages
  - Components
    - ExternalSystems
      - Default.cshtml
- Views
  - Shared
    - Components
      - ExternalSystems
        - Default.cshtml`

Class file

```
public class Default : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly Models.PermissionRegisterContext _context;

    public Default(Models.PermissionRegisterContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var externalSystems = await _context.ExternalSystem.ToListAsync();

        return View("Default", externalSystems);
    }
}
```

within `Pages/Index.cshtml` i'v tried to include this component by trial & error (i'm learning this stuff after all):

`@await Component.InvokeAsync("ExternalSystems");
@await Component.InvokeAsync("/Pages/Components/ExternalSystems");
@await Component.InvokeAsync("/Pages/Components/ExternalSystems/Default");
@await Component.InvokeAsync("/Pages/Components/ExternalSystems/Default.cshtml");
@await Component.InvokeAsync("/Views/Shared/ExternalSystems");`

I expected that exception will show places searched like it does for `@Html.Partial`:

> InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'none' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Pages/none.cshtml /Views/Shared/none.cshtml

However for every single call to `@await Component.InvokeAsync` it spits this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component '.Pages.Identities.IndexModel'.

First of all, it doesn't show me paths searched. Second, wait what? Why are you telling me something about Pages.Identities? Yes, I have that model, but it is nowhere referenced in neither `Pages/Index.cshtml` or View Component i'm trying to include.

Could someone please provide me with a guidance to determine: How view component paths are searched? For Razor Pages it is [not documented](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6278), only in [3rd party site](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components). 
Anyway it doesn't work that way for me - what would be the debugging steps? Console debug doesn't show anything useful.

dotnet 2.0.7

Comment: What does your `ExternalSystems` view component class look like?  The error seems to indicate you have not defined an `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` method.

Comment: @Brad I do have that method. Edited question to include class.

Comment: Your class name might be causing a problem.  Try changing the class name to `ExternalSystemsViewComponent`.  This should find the view file `Default.cshtml` in the folder `Views/Shared/Components/ExternalSystems`.  And simply `return View(externalSystems);` in your invoke method.

Comment: @Brad, I tried, but it doesn't help. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#creating-a-view-component), I have any of 3 options:
1. Deriving from ViewComponent
2. Decorating a class with the [ViewComponent] attribute, or deriving from a class with the [ViewComponent] attribute
3. Creating a class where the name ends with the suffix ViewComponent

Comment: @Brad, it's the first time I try to make ViewComponent and just try naming classes/files/paths in any combination I can imagine and cannot succeed. But the thing that bugs me is why on earth he says that `Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync'` on a IndexModel defined within `/Pages/Identities/Index.cshtml.cs` no matter what I put within `@await Component.InvokeAsync("...")`

Comment: I'v opened an issue https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2348 to ask if exception details could include locations searched for ViewComponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, my mistake was that I didn't see I have decorated `...Pages.Identities.IndexModel` with `[ViewComponent]`. It was unintentional and was just trying to make ViewComponents work by trial & error and failed to see this mistake.

Basically dotnet discovered type that didn't have either Invoke/InvokeAsync function and thus was stuck on that exception.

I validated that these paths are searched when providing "HelloWorld" as view name:

- /Pages/Components/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cshtml
- /Views/Shared/Components/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have created a view component as follows :

```
public class ExternalSystems : ViewComponent 
{  

    public ExternalSystems()
    {
      //constructor can have dependencies injected. 
    }     

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke() 
    {
       //View is a helper method available in classes inherited
       //from ViewComponent that returns an instance of 
       //ViewViewComponentResult. It has multiple overloads as described 
       //later.
       return View(viewName,viewModel);           
    }
}
```

View method has multiple overrides :

```
  View() - use default view for view component without any viewmodel
  View(viewModel) - use default view for view  component with specified viewmodel
  View(viewName) - use specified view for view component without any viewmodel
  View(viewName,viewModel) - use specified view for view component with specified viewmodel
```

When you try to render this view component from a Controller, view will be looked up at following locations :

1. "**/Views/{ControllerName}/Components/ExternalSystems/{ViewName}.cshtml**" . 

   So, if you are using HomeController and have specified viewName as  ExternalSystemsView in the View(viewName,viewModel) call , your path becomes
   /Views/Home/Components/ExternalSystems/ExternalSystemsView.cshtml . This allows each controller to have its own custom view for the view returned by view component.
2. If the ExternalSystemsView.cshtml is not located at above path , it will be looked up at **/Views/Shared/Components/ExternalSystems/ExternalSystemsView.cshtml**
3. You can override the lookup position by passing the complete path of view - **View("Views/Shared/Components/Common/YourView.cshtml")** while calling View(viewName,viewModel) from your ViewComponent's Invoke method.

   **Note : If you don't specify a viewName, it defaults to Default.cshtml which is different from Index.html used for controllers**

For your case, @await Component.InvokeAsync("ExternalSystems") is the correct call as it expects the viewcomponent name as parameter. ViewName will be picked up from what you have passed as the viewName parameter value to View(viewName,viewModel) call in your ViewComponent's Invoke method and will default to Default.cshtml if no viewname has been specified.

Comment: Thanks. However you have provided answer for MVC. My question is about Razor Pages and me trying to find out whether `/Pages/Components` is a valid location which is searched by Razor Pages when including View components. Thanks for additional info tho.